Location popup not showing in offline/not connected to any wifi if the device in airplane/flight mode
Hello In the code My Android device is in flight mode not showing location popup.But with the below already location permission was given in flight mode still showing every-time.Don't want to show in flight mode if the location is off that time showing popup not every time.
Now another scenario if the device is not in flight calling else part that is working as expected.
Can any one help me with the same else code method want to implement if the device is in flight mode as well.
A.java:
String bluetoothStatus = jObj.optString(Constant.VALUE);
                boolean isAirplaneModeOn = Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON,0) != 0;
                if(isAirplaneModeOn) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    builder.setTitle("Airplane Mode is on");
                    builder.setMessage("Please turn off Airplane Mode to enable location services");
                    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new 

Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                            context.startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                } else {
                    pesManager.checkPermissionoffline(context,bluetoothStatus);
                }

B.java:
public void checkPermissionoffline(Activity activity, String value) {
        if (bleAdapter == null) {
            final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
            bleAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        }
        if (value != null && value.equals(String.valueOf(Constant.BLE_DISABLED))) {
            requestBluetoothEnable(activity);
        } else {
            if (!bleAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                bluetoothPermissionResult(Constant.BLE_DISABLED);
            } else {
                if (bleAdapter != null && bleAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    if (!hasLocationPermissions(activity)) {
                        requestLocationPermission(activity);
                    } else {
                        requestDeviceLocationSettings(activity);
                    }
                } else {
                    requestBluetoothEnable(activity);
                }
            }
        }
    }

